# Merge the Segue and UIStoryboardSegue tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

iOS 5 introduced a new feature, Storyboards.  The transition between views in these storyboards are called `segues`.  I've noticed users using both the [segue](/questions/tagged/segue) and [uistoryboardsegue](/questions/tagged/uistoryboardsegue) tags.  Both are technically correct, but [uistoryboardsegue](/questions/tagged/uistoryboardsegue) is less ambiguous.

Should these tags be merged?

Answer (score 1):

I think the class tag [uistoryboardsegue](/questions/tagged/uistoryboardsegue) should be reserved for problems using the class directly, and [segue](/questions/tagged/segue) should be used for questions related to the segue process but where the primary problem is not with the class per se.